# Apache Ignite 2.14: Getting "partition data has been lost" error for ignite-sys-atomic-cache

Tags: ignite

I have an Apache Ignite 2.14 cluster of 3 nodes running on Kubernetes. All my caches have one backup copy.

After enabling persistence on the default data region a couple of months ago, I started getting the exception `CacheInvalidStateException: Failed to execute the cache operation (all partition owners have left the grid, partition data has been lost)` when one or two nodes restarted either as a result of deployment or for some other reason.

It was worrying but I learned to fix it by running `control.sh --cache reset_lost_partitions cacheName`.

This time after two nodes restarted due to some transient failure I started getting an error which I couldn't fix by running the mentioned command:

`Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheInvalidStateException: Failed to execute the cache operation (all partition owners have left the grid, partition data has been lost) [cacheName=ignite-sys-atomic-cache@default-ds-group, partition=985, key=UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=985, val=GridCacheInternalKeyImpl [name=alias, grpName=default-ds-group], hasValBytes=true]] at rg.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtTopologyFutureAdapter.validateKey(GridDhtTopologyFutureAdapter.java:214)`

Looks like this time this issue involved a system cache `ignite-sys-atomic-cache@default-ds-group`. I guess it is related to the AtomicSequence object that I use in the application to get IDs generated. The error occurs exactly when I'm trying to use AtomicLong.

The question are:

- Why it might happen?
- Is it possible to fix it without destroying the cluster and reloading all the data from scratch (it would take a day or two).
- How to prevent similar issues in the future?

Thank you in advance!

P.S. On GridGain Portal the following error is reported: Cache [default-ds-group] has zero partition copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix it you can run:

```
control.sh --cache reset_lost_partitions default-ds-group,default-volatile-ds-group@volatileDsMemPlc
```

Some system caches are partitioned and can loss the partitions as well as normal user caches.

The command above should help in your case.

As the work around you can change the backup factor and change the group:

https://www.gridgain.com/sdk/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/AtomicConfiguration.html#setBackups-int-
https://www.gridgain.com/sdk/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/AtomicConfiguration.html#setGroupName-java.lang.String-

If the structure is volatile, it will have the group name "default-volatile-ds-group". Otherwise, if no group name is given, the name will be "default-ds-group". As far as I know it has some cache creation logic based on this.

Try the following example for your data structure:

```
    AtomicConfiguration cfg = new AtomicConfiguration().setGroupName("testgrp");

    cfg.setBackups(1);
    cfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);

    IgniteAtomicReference<String> ref = ignite.atomicReference("ref", cfg, "d", true);
```

Regards,
Andrei

Comment: Thank you for your response! I managed to fix this error by running Reset Lost Partition on GridGain Portal. It worked this time. Interestingly, the lost partition list showed more than a hundred of lost partitions belonging to ignite-sys-atomic-cache@default-ds-group. I wonder if this cache is persisted when persistence is enabled for the default group?

Comment: if ds is not volotile then data structures will be stored in default region. Volotile structures will use volatileDsMemPlc region that is fully inmemory.

Volotile DSs are REENTRANT_LOCK, SEMAPHORE and COUNT_DOWN_LATCH. So if you have persistent default region, all other DS will be stored there.

Comment: Just add more backups to your data structure and don't stop more nodes than your backup number. Default backup factor is zero as you said above.

Comment: Understood, thank you. I forgot to mention that I use the .Net bindings for Ignite and the configuration code you kindly provided earlier don't seem to be available in the Net version. AtomicConfiguration is present in .Net but group name cannot be changed, and it doesn't seem to be possible to pass AtomicConfiguration to GetAtomicSequence().

Comment: I am not an expert in .NET API, I need time to test this. However, DS can be created in the separate Java client, but after that you can use them from your .NET code. Some kind of WA.

Comment: .NET API does not provide `AtomicConfiguration` for individual atomics. But you can set the defaults in `IgniteConfiguration.AtomicConfiguration`. Or use a Java service/computeTask from .NET to create an atomic with custom config.

Comment: @PavelTupitsyn Understood, thank you for your response. Changing group name doesn't seem to be possible but some other settings may be configured.